# as3 air app for phone - slight delay tween after button press

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have noticed a slight delay on my animations when I press a button. The audio will respond asap etc.. but the animation has a second or two delay. I notice it more on the iPhone.

It also happens if I want to show an MovieClip for the first time.

if I do /// Press code
`addChild(myMC);` there is a delay on this too.

I notice its usually a mouse click event.
`intro.about.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, example);`/// and example.

Could this be a coding issue? Is there a way to ensure faster animation with tighter code?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking (**and this may not be your issue**, but likely is), when using a touch device, the container (iOS in this case) will wait a short period before dispatching the click/mouseup event.  It/They do this because they need to decide if you're doing a gesture/swipe.

You can get around this by either using the `MOUSE_DOWN` event instead of `CLICK`, or even better, use the TOUCH events - as shown below:

in your document class (or anywhere really), you need to initialize the touch-mode.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT
```

Then the equivalent of mouse down, is touch begin:

```
TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN
```

And the equivalent of mouse up is touch end:

```
TouchEvent.TOUCH_END
```

They are found in these packages:

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
```

Even if your issue ends up being something else, please don't donwvote as it may be useful to others searching with a similar problem

Comment: Thanks for the AWESOME answer. I have not tired it yet but I will soon. Just a quick question. You think this is the case if it calls the audio right away? My button calls audio and an animation. I would think if its waiting for the button click it would not call the audio. Maybe I am imagining that. I will test it. Thanks again for the great answer. I will let you know asap. :)

Comment: Is the code where you play audio in the same mouse handler as the code that makes the animation start?  If so, then there is probably another issue.